# Is it safe to cast fgetc() result to short if I use it only with file opened in "rb" mode?

Tags: c, file

I'm writing Kotlin/Native library for file management in C (surprise! K/N does not have this feature, haha) and I'm somewhat stuck - why file sized in 708651 bytes takes 4 times more space in memory when I use my functions to manage files? 4 times!!! And I just got realized that files are using values only from -1 to 255 if they are opened in "rb" mode (-1 for EOF). Is it safe to use such function:

```c
short readNextByte(FILE *fp) {
    return (short)fgetc(fp);
}
```

assuming I can provide enough powerful abstraction level already in Kotlin code?

P.S. I'm not so good in C, and probably it's very basic question, so I'll understand your dislike

Comment: But a returned value of -1 is not a character, it's an error condition. You have to handle that error condition, if you just store -1 in some buffer, you loose the ability to determine what this error was...

Comment: `fgetc()` reads one byte but does not return a `char` or a `short`: its type is `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know it

Comment: @Бодя паук There is no problem with the function.

Comment: You may get better responses, if you show the code which actually stores something (provide a [mre]). Also, please use either the C or the C++ tag.

Comment: Why do you want `short`? If the file actually contains `short` values then you must read the right number of bytes with `fread()`. Only use `short` in your code if you have a specific reason why you should not use `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have my own implementation of fread which is more memory-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why file sized in 708651 bytes takes 4 times more space in memory when I use my functions to manage files?

If the file takes four times more space in memory than the actual file size, this suggests you are storing one four-byte `int` in memory for each byte in the file.

If you wish to read the file using `fgetc` and store the entire file in memory, then examine each value returned from `fgetc` to see if it is an error or end-of-file indication (has the value of `EOF`). If it does, handle the error or end-of-file. Otherwise, convert the result to an `unsigned char` and store only that.

> Is it safe to cast fgetc() result to short if I use it only with file opened in "rb" mode?

No. The C standard does not guarantee the value of `EOF` can be represented in a `short`, only that it is negative and is representable in an `int`. Converting it to `short` might work in one C implementation and not in another.

You should compare the result of `fgetc` to `EOF` before converting it to `short` or any type narrower than `int`. After determining it is not `EOF`, it is safe to convert it to `unsigned char`.

> … assuming I can provide enough powerful abstraction level already in Kotlin code?

This question is unclear. `fgetc` is for reading raw bytes from a file. It is unclear what sort of abstraction you would provide or what you want to use `fgetc` for.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, it is really very abstract. Talking about abstraction level, I want to make it more `java.io.File`-like because of target users are Kotlin programmers